# postgres gem error after yosemite upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, osx-yosemite

I installed the Yosemite beta the other night and now I am having issues with my postgres gem:

```
$ rails s
/Users/julio/GIT_REPOS/maztaplan2/vendor/bundle/gems/pg-0.17.1/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require': dlopen(/Users/julio/GIT_REPOS/maztaplan2/vendor/bundle/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0/pg-0.17.1/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib (LoadError)
```

I tried updating my gems with `gem update system` but it said there was nothing to update. I also did a `bundle update` with no change.

Comment: So there seems to be an issue with it. Hope this helps. I had the same issue. This fixed it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447736/unable-to-connect-to-postgresql-database-after-upgrading-to-yosemite-10-10

Answer (score 0):

I found this.

cd /usr/local/var/postgres

mkdir pg_tblspc pg_twophase pg_stat_tmp

It worked for me.